# Stop script in Maxscript

Tags: maxscript

Is there a command in Maxscript that allows you to stop a script early? Say for example the script relies on having a single object as a selection. If there's nothing to select then it won't work.

```
myObj = $
if ($ == undefined) then STOP
-- rest of code
```

where STOP represents is the elusive or fictional stop command

Rather than having to do a test like:

```
myObj = $
if ($ != undefined) then
(
--rest of code
)
```

Which is fine, but it does mean to put the majority of the script in brackets - which I find it makes the code a but uglier to edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends, you can usually use `return` to force an early exit. This will work even in case of event handlers as they are basically just functions:

```
rollout test "Test"
(
    button btn "Exception"

    on btn pressed do
    (
        if selection.count != 1 do
            return messageBox "Selection count expected to be one."
        if NOT isKindOf selection[1] Editable_poly do
            return messageBox "Object not an Editable Poly."
        btn.text = selection[1].name
    )
)
createDialog test
```

Due to some implementation details, if used in a body of a loop or somewhere else where it might be executed multiple times, it would make the whole script slower, though.

If you only want to exit the script and only print information in the listener, `throw` might be a better function to use.

```
    if selection.count != 1 do
        throw "Selection count expected to be one."
    if NOT isKindOf selection[1] Editable_poly do
        throw "Object not an Editable Poly"
    print selection[1].name
```

However in most cases what you are currently using is the most fitting solution. If you want to improve it (especially if you find yourself writing the same piece of code over and over again), you can write a custom struct similar to, for example, `Filters`:

```
    #Struct:Filters(
        GetModOrObj:<fn>; Public,
        Is_EditSpline:<fn>; Public,
        CanSwitchTo_Segment:<fn>; Public,
        HasBaseObjectProperty:<fn>; Public,
        ...
        Is_EditPolyMod:<fn>; Public,
        Is_This_EditPolyObj:<fn>; Public,
        Is_EditPatch:<fn>; Public,
        CanSwitchTo_Face:<fn>; Public)
```

Answer (score 1):

use exit, here's a simple example: a = 100

```
while True do

(

    a -= 1

    print a

    if a == 20 do

    (

        print "a is equal to 20!" 

        exit

    )

)
```

Comment: That only works within loops (it doesn't apply to the example OP provided).

Comment: @Swordslayer true, it only works with for and while loops, I've read the post quickly and had the impression that he posted a small piece of his code that is inside some loop! my fault! :)